# Java different ways of creating objects

Tags: java

Can any one tell me the difference between these two object creation

**Method 1 :**

```
Superclass ob = new Childclass();
```

**Method 2 :**

```
Childclass ob = new Shildclass();
```

What will be the difference between both objects and why.

Thanks,
Vijesh

Comment: Look up java inheritance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Your Java textbook should explain. If you don’t understand its explanation, I suggest you try asking a more specific question. :-)

Comment: Shildclass- that's a mistake...

Answer (score 1):

The difference is:

```
Superclass a = new ChildClass();
```

is declared as a type Superclass instance, meaning it's limited to the members of the Superclass.

```
ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
```

is of type ChildClass and has access to all the members of both the ChildClass, and those inherited from Superclass.

Answer (score 0):

The object creations are the same.  In both cases you are creating an instance of the `Childclass`.

The difference between those two snippets is in what you do with the object references **after** the object creation.

By assigning the object reference to a variable of type `Superclass` you are temporarily "hiding" some aspects of the `Childclass`-ness of the object.  But the object remains an instance of `Childclass`, as illustrated by this:

```
Superclass ob = new Childclass();
System.out.println(ob.getClass());  // prints "Childclass"
```